# zf2 'Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\Db\Adapter\Profiler\ProfilerInterface"

Tags: dependency-injection, dependencies, zend-framework2, adapter

This is the warning

```
   zf2 'Invalid instantiator of type "NULL" for "Zend\Db\Adapter\Profiler\ProfilerInterface"
```

So, this is my local.config.php, and somehow it the Adapter expects I am setting a profile with the function setProfile. The setProfile function is located at 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'. I am a complete idiot with programming, I don't know how to solve this, I don't even know what parameter it DOES expect instead of NULL, and I don't even want a profiler.....

```
include (__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/Core/config/function.local.php');

$dbParams = $functionVars['dbParams'];

return array(
  'di' => array(
     'allowed_controllers' => array(
       'Application\Controller\IndexController',
       'Login\Controller\FormController',
       'Login\Controller\RegisterController',
     ),
     'instance' => array(
       'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => array(
         'parameters' => array(
            'driver' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo',
         ),
       ),
       'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo' => array(
         'parameters' => array(
            'connection' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection',
         ),
       ),
       'Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection' => array(
         'parameters' => array(
           'connectionParameters' => array(
             'dsn'            => "mysql:dbname=" . $dbParams['database'] . ";host=" . $dbParams['hostname'],
             'username'       => $dbParams['username'],
             'password'       => $dbParams['password'],
             'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''),
           ),
         ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: What do you want and what are you trying to do?

Comment: Never mind, I use the Service Manager now... was tired of all the hassle